# 4+E 6mm sq. better than 2+E 10 mm sq. for UK 240V?

Tags: mains

I can get 4+E 6mm sq. and wire L,L,N,N,E.

On paper this looks better than 10mm sq., L, N, E.

But I am unsure if there is a hidden level of de-rating.

Which one is better for a long run 40A supply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single conductor wire of the appropriate rating.

If you use two conductors in parallel, then a break in one would be 'silent', your equipment would carry on working. However if you then stressed the link to a current that needed the full area, you would overheat the one remaining conductor.

If you use only a single conductor, any break would be noticeable.

Physics-wise, 12 mm<sup>2</sup> will give you lower voltage drop than 10 mm<sup>2</sup> of course.

Answer (score 1):

10mm² is less than 2 x 6mm².  But you're planning to double up the lives and neutrals, but not the earth.  So you end up with a total of 12mm² of current carrying conductors, but only 6mm² of earth.  You'll need to do the calculations to see if this will be adequate.